# Can two separate hibernate in two jvm on same machine get confuse and use same ehcache files

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, ehcache

I have two separate `Hibernate` instances running in two different jvm on same physical machine.

Both hibernate are using the same `ehcache.xml` setting file and both hibernate jvm uses a common class like:

```
@Entity
class Parent {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
   @Cache(region = "myCache", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
   private List<Children> childrens;
}
```

Point to Note: I am using the`@cache annotation with region defined`.

Ehcache setting xml:

```
    <cache name="myCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    eternal="false"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    timeToIdleSeconds="600"
    timeToLiveSeconds="6000"
    diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
    />
```

**Now if Process `A`**
[0] start transaction

[1] Reads the parent object and then

[2] reads all the childrens in the collection, which in turn put children object in hibernate's mycache region of ehcache, which in turn makes the inmemory object count to full and overflow children object to disk and file get saved in `myCahce.data`

[3] and then process `A` deletes the children objects from the collection.

[4] transaction complete

---

And the other process `B` upon getting the transaction complete msg, reads the parent object and Now if we try to run `parent.getChildren()` i get the

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists[my.package.class.entity#3218]
```

This means process `B` hibernate did got the children object identifier value from somewhere but when it actually try to load the object from db it couldn't find it.

Ideally it should not have got the identifier value.

---

**Question**

Is it happening because both hibernate instance end up using the same `myCache.data` and since `diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds = 120`, object in file cache does not get dirty flag `on` until 120 sec.

So process `B` ends up loading the `ids` of the collection objects from the cache file but when it actually try to load from db it does not find the row and hence throwing the error ?

---

System details:

```
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
<version>4.2.2.Final</version>

<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>4.2.2.Final</version>
```